# Javascript plugins design pattern like jQuery

Tags: javascript, plugin-pattern

Could someone write down a very simple basic example in javascript to conceptualize (and hopefully make me understand) how the jQuery plugin design pattern is done and how it works?

I'm not interested in how creating plugin for jQuery (so **no jQuery code here at all**).
I'm interested in a simple explanation (maybe with a bit of Javascript code) to explain **how it is done the plugin concept**.

Plz do not reply me to go and read jQuery code, I tried, but I it's too complex, otherwise I would have not post a question here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

jQuery has a library of functions stored in an internal object named `fn`. These are the ones that you can call on every jQuery object.

When you do `$("div.someClass")` you get a jQuery object containing all `<div>` elements of that class. Now you can do `$("div.someClass").each( someFunction )` to apply `someFunction` to each of them. This means, that `each()` is one of the functions stored in `fn` (a built-in one in this case).

If you extend (add to) the internal `fn` object, then you automatically make available your custom function to the same syntax. Lets assume you have a function that logs all elements to the console, called `log()`. You could append this function to `$.fn`, and then use it as `$("div.someClass").log()`.

Every function appended to the `fn` object will be called in such a way that *inside* the function body, the `this` keyword will point to the jQuery object you've used.

Common practice is to return `this` at the end of the custom function, so that method chaining does not break: `$("div.someClass").log().each( someFunction )`.

There are several ways to append functions to the `$.fn` object, some safer than others. A pretty safe one is to do:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  foo: function() {
    this.each( function() { console.log(this.tagName); } );
    return this;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomalak already posted almost everything You need to know.

There is one last thing that helps jQuery do the trick with the **this** keyword.

it's amethod called apply()

```
var somefunction=function(){
alert(this.text);
}
var anObject={text:"hello"};

somefunction.apply(anObject);
//alert "hello" will happen
```

It really helps in creating abstractions so that framework/plugin users would just use **this** as intuition tells them, whatever there is inside Your code

Answer (score 0):

It works, as many other js frameworks, using javascript prototype orientation.

For instance you can declare a simple function

```
var alertHelloWorld = function() {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

And then tie it to an existing object (including DOM nodes)

```
document.doMyAlert = alertHelloWorld;
```

If you do this

```
document.doMyAlert();
```

The alertHelloWorld function will be executed

You can read more about javascript object prototyping [here](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately your example does not use prototyping at all. This works because in JavaScript, functions are first class objects and can be passed and assigned like any other variable.

Comment: yes, prototype object exists on objects declared as such, it works in a similar way.
I could have copy/paste from the bottom link

Object.prototype.inObj = 1;
 
function A()
{
    this.inA = 2;
}
 
A.prototype.inAProto = 3;
 
B.prototype = new A;            // Hook up A into B's prototype chain
B.prototype.constructor = B;
function B()
{
    this.inB = 4;
}
 
B.prototype.inBProto = 5;
 
x = new B;
document.write(x.inObj + ', ' + x.inA + ', ' + x.inAProto + ', ' + x.inB + ', ' + x.inBProto);